# How to test on earlier versions on ios SDK

Tags: ios, xcode

I have xcode 4.2 installed which only allows me to launch a simulator for SDK 4.3 and 5.0. I would like to test on a simulator for SDK 4.0. How would I do this?

From the research I have done it seems that installing an earlier version of xcode will overwrite some of my xcode 4.2 files? I looks as if you have to start with installing the earliest version and end with the latest version. But I'm not sure.

I know there are many questions like this already, but nothing that covers exactly what I'm asking, the other examples use different version in different orders and don't seem to provide a really solid guide on achieving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download the old Xcode and extract simulator and sdk folders.
Than copy it to your xcode path.

that's all.

Comment: Where could I find an older version of xcode? I looked through the developer website but all I find is an older version with the 4.3 SDK? any ideas?